# Entity Graph does not work in Entity Layer but work in Repository Layer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have a chain of entities **User** -> **CryptoWallet** -> **List<**CryptoCount**>**

1.

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuidFromIp" , strategy = "org.hibernate.id.uuid.CustomVersionOneStrategy")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid_gen_strategy")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "user_name")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "crypto_wallet_id")
    private CryptoWallet cryptoWallet;
}
```

2. 

```
public class CryptoWallet {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "balance")
    private BigDecimal balance;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cryptoWallet", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CryptoCount> cryptoCounts;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "cryptoWallet")
    private User walletOwner;
}
```

3. 

```
public class CryptoCount {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "crypto_id")
    private CryptoCurrency cryptoCurrency;

    @Column(name = "count")
    private BigDecimal countOfCrypto;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "crypto_wallet_id")
    private CryptoWallet cryptoWallet;
}
```

My task is to load  All CryptoCount By CryptoWalletOwnerId in one request

When i use next method in Repository Layer everything work correctly(with one query).

```
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"cryptoCurrency","cryptoWallet","cryptoWallet.walletOwner"})
List<CryptoCount> findAllByCryptoWalletWalletOwnerId(UUID id);
```

**BUT**

When I annotate **CryptoCount** like this:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "CryptoCountWithCurrencyAndWallet",attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "cryptoCurrency"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "cryptoWallet")
})
```

And CryptoWallet like this:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "WalletWithCryptoCountsAndWalletOwner", attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "cryptoCounts"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "walletOwner",subgraph = "UserWithWallet")
}, subgraphs = {
        @NamedSubgraph(name = "UserWithWallet", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("cryptoWallet"))
})
```

And also **User** like this:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "UserWithWallet",attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode("cryptoWallet")
},subgraphs = {
        @NamedSubgraph(name = "userWithWallet", attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode("cryptoWallet")})
})
```

And also use next method in Repository:

```
@EntityGraph(value = "CryptoCountWithCurrencyAndWallet")
    List<CryptoCount> findAllByCryptoWalletWalletOwnerId(UUID id);
```

I get two database queries instead of one. Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "CryptoCountWithCurrencyAndWallet",attributeNodes = {
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "cryptoCurrency"),
        @NamedAttributeNode(value = "cryptoWallet",subgraph = "withWalletOwner")
},subgraphs = {
        @NamedSubgraph(name = "withWalletOwner",attributeNodes = {@NamedAttributeNode("walletOwner")})
})
```

In **CryptoCount** solved the problem